# How to delete a parent without deleting the children in a OneToMany Association is Symfony 5.0.5

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

So I have a User entity and a Department entity:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", mappedBy="department")
     */
    private $employees;
```

and

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Department", inversedBy="employees")
     */
    private $department;
```

And I'm using EasyAdmin Bundle
I want to be able to delete a Department that has employees, but without deleting them.
but I always get this error:

> There is a ForeignKeyConstraintViolationException for the Doctrine entity associated with "Department". Solution: disable the "delete" action for this entity or configure the "cascade={"remove"}" attribute for the related property in the Doctrine entity. Full exception: An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM department WHERE id = ?' with params [4]:

I've tried overriding the 'easy_admin.pre_delete' event adding this function to remove all associations before deleting my entity:

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            'easy_admin.pre_delete' => array('deleteAssociations'),
        );
    }
public function deleteAssociations(GenericEvent $event) {

        $entity = $event->getSubject();

        if (!($entity instanceof Department)) {
            return;
        }

        foreach($entity->getEmployees() as $employee) {
            $entity->removeEmployee($employee);
        }
        $event['entity'] = $entity;
    }
```

but it still shows the same error. if someone has any idea why, thanks for any answer

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:
I should be using

> easy_admin.pre_remove

and not:

> easy_admin.pre_delete